# Running gnuplot in background with Qt4

Tags: linux, background, qt4, gnuplot, system-calls

I tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424455/c-and-gnuplot) for plotting some simulation results in a program using Qt4 for the configuration interface. The problem is that in order not to prevent the main results from appearing in a text area, I have to call gnuplot in background. For that, I use:  `system("gnuplot plotCmdFile.txt &");`. In the text file I put `pause -1` in the final line, but it doesn't help and gnuplot's window closes immediately. If I don't run gnuplot in background, the program blocks after showing the plot window. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you are trying to do--do you want the simulation results to pop up on the screen and stay there?  You might try passing gnuplot the --persist/-p option to make it stay on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Open `gnuplot` with `QProcess` instead of `system().` Use `writeLine(),` `readLine()` to interact with `gnuplot`. This is same as you open terminal and enter commands.